# How can I get the value of the field_percentage field?

Tags: theming, paragraphs, 9

I'm trying to create a custom template for the paragraph-progress-bar component.
The component I created has 2 fields: title (field_title) and percentage (field_percentage, integer field limited from 0 to 100).

How can I get the value of the *field_percentage* field to pass it in the width of the progress bar code?

I'm trying with `style="width: {{ content.field_percentuale ~ '%'}};"` but it returns `Array`.

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'paragraph',
    'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
    view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    not paragraph.isPublished() ? 'paragraph--unpublished'
  ]
%}
{% block paragraph %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {% block content %}
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{ content.field_percentuale ~ '%'}};" aria-valuenow="{{content.field_percentuale}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{ content.field_titolo }}</div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

Comment: Does `paragraph.field_percentuale.value` work?

Comment: Yes thank you !!